# Dtype to nparray.dtype

Tags: python, tensorflow, pywavelets

My intention is to use pywavelet on a tensor in tensorflow, with the sentence

```
pywt.dwt(input,'db1')
```

The error was

```
Cannot convert DType to numpy.dtype
```

Input is a `Tensor("Reshape_18:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)` from MNIST dataset.

I try with the sentence `pywt.dwt(input.dtype.as_numpy_dtype,'db1')` and the error "invalid **array_struct**".

Answer (score 0):

`pywt.dwt()` takes a 1D array.

But looks like you have a 4D array so you'll wanna use a `pywt.dwtn()` [Docs here](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/nd-dwt-and-idwt.html#single-level-dwtn).